# Gradle not resolving dependencies of dependencies

Tags: java, spring, gradle, dependency-management

Gradle won't build because it can't resolve dependencies of dependencies.   For example,  I have a project **MyStarterWeb** which has a dependency on spring-boot-starter-web:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.2'
}
```

I have a second project, **MyFirstEndPoint**, that extends/uses/is dependent upon **MyStarterWeb**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'group: 'com.mygroup', name: 'MyStarterWeb', version: '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

After reading the Gradle docs (which are contradicting, confusing and of little value), I understood that Gradle would resolve all the dependencies for the **MyFirstEndPoint** project without having to list the spring dependencies listed in **MyStarterWeb**.  But, this is not the case:

```
error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
```

Any help/explanation/guidance/clarification on the poor Gradle docs is greatly appreciated.  If there's an RTFM link that I missed, please share

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this issue with Gradle not resolving transitive dependencies (using Gradle 6.0+) for a self-published artifact/library, the solution was to change the **MyStarterWeb** project to use the *java-library* plugin:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'java-library'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}
```

and then to change the dependencies in **MyStarterWeb** to use the *api* configuration instead of *implementation* configuration.

```
dependencies {
api 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.2'
}
```

That allowed the **MyFirstEndPoint** project to resolve all transitive dependencies and only have to specify the **MyStarterWeb** dependency

```
dependencies {
implementation group:'bla', name: 'MyStarterWeb', version: '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```